# How to know request cookies when a URL sent to server as a request using Python

Tags: python, cookies, request-headers

I want to know request headers of URL or cookie value in headers.

```
url = 'https://research.ibfd.org/endecapod/myN=3+10+4293760389+4293746984&Nu=global_rollup_key&Np=2&Nao=20&Nty=0&Ns=decision_date_sortable|1'
```

Headers for that URL are

```
headers = {
        "Accept":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "Connection":"keep-alive",
        "Cookie": "optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1575288961321r0.6329519991798649; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D; _ga=GA1.2.693353487.1575288963; _hjid=cfef24b9-ec0f-4677-90eb-6f25e4a4351e; s_ecid=MCMID%7C89844361514127015796100074732098692046; optimizelySegments=%7B%22785891794%22%3A%22gc%22%2C%22786481600%22%3A%22false%22%2C%22787091486%22%3A%22referral%22%7D; angular-ab-tests-ibfd_preview=no; IBFD_SESSION=1xwvMTmbcR714KGplMpDLoYVqTikDSbU; _hjIncludedInSample=1; AMCVS_2F71365B5AA928340A495E05%40AdobeOrg=1; s_cc=true; wt_tags=SUB:kbase:masna.venu@thomsonreuters.com::username:; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=1; has_js=1; _gid=GA1.2.1180329552.1595404659; s_ppvl=Home%2520-%2520Tax%2520Research%2520Platform%2520-%2520IBFD%2C90%2C90%2C588%2C1422%2C588%2C1280%2C720%2C1.35%2CP; s_ppn=Search%20-%20Tax%20Research%20Platform%20-%20IBFD; s_nr=1595405276724-Repeat; AMCV_2F71365B5AA928340A495E05%40AdobeOrg=1075005958%7CMCIDTS%7C18466%7CMCMID%7C89844361514127015796100074732098692046%7CMCOPTOUT-1595412476s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C4.4.1; s_ppv=Search%2520-%2520Tax%2520Research%2520Platform%2520-%2520IBFD%2C100%2C75%2C21135.408203125%2C360%2C588%2C1280%2C720%2C1.35%2CL",
        #"Cookie":"optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1575288961321r0.6329519991798649; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D; _ga=GA1.2.693353487.1575288963; _hjid=cfef24b9-ec0f-4677-90eb-6f25e4a4351e; s_ecid=MCMID%7C89844361514127015796100074732098692046; optimizelySegments=%7B%22785891794%22%3A%22gc%22%2C%22786481600%22%3A%22false%22%2C%22787091486%22%3A%22referral%22%7D; angular-ab-tests-ibfd_preview=no; _gid=GA1.2.1850576194.1594914732; IBFD_SESSION=IstWIRdSWRTYlHdmcgyqwaigHIGkr6Q3; AMCVS_2F71365B5AA928340A495E05%40AdobeOrg=1; _hjIncludedInSample=1; s_ppn=Search%20-%20Tax%20Research%20Platform%20-%20IBFD; s_ppvl=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_cc=true; wt_tags=SUB:kbase:masna.venu@thomsonreuters.com::username:; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=1; AMCV_2F71365B5AA928340A495E05%40AdobeOrg=1075005958%7CMCIDTS%7C18461%7CMCMID%7C89844361514127015796100074732098692046%7CMCOPTOUT-1594974899s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C4.4.1; s_nr=1594967699992-Repeat; s_ppv=Search%2520-%2520Tax%2520Research%2520Platform%2520-%2520IBFD%2C100%2C91%2C3987%2C759%2C642%2C1280%2C720%2C1.35%2CP",
        "Host":"research.ibfd.org",
        "Referer":"https://research.ibfd.org/",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest":"empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode":"cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site":"same-origin",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36"
    }
```

I have got those headers from chrome developer tools. In those headers, cookie value is changing everyday. I want to get that cookie value by some script.

Can anyone help me to get that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use response `.cookies`

Comment: resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(resp.cookies) when I executed above line I am getting <RequestsCookieJar[]>

Comment: yes, like this. Note that  `.cookies` is an object, not a string

Comment: @Marat when I use response.cookies i am getting <RequestsCookieJar[]>

Comment: How can I get values of that object?

Comment: and I am seeing it is empty.

Comment: the server sent no cookies; so, the subsequent request is expected to send no cookies as well. Most likely, these cookies were set by JavaScript, which isn't processed by requests

Comment: Ok. Thank you for that information. Is there anyway to know all request headers of URL by some script(not from developer tools of chrome).

Comment: I guess there is some terminology issue, since you are sending the request and thus fully control its headers. If you are asking about response, then `responce.headers` contains everything the server sent back, including cookies (btw, if you aren't going to change anything it's easier to reuse cookies this way)